# Permission for external Client

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, user, unique-permissions, external

I have set up a SharePoint site that I have Owners, Members and Visitors. I need to provide member permissions to a Client but only allow the Client to see Working Documents that maybe Document Library, List or Folders. Can I create a Page and provide access to external client and have Document Library, List or Folders in this Page.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new page, insert document library and list web parts into the page, then go to site pages library to share the newly created page with external users.